# Getting currency data out of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, finance

I have a button dropdown that you can select different currencies from. When you select one, it replaces the button value with that currency type, and displays the currency symbol in a span in front of an input.

I have done some refactoring where I now have just one function `getCurrency()` that accepts parameters and inserts the proper values, but in here `$(".dropdown-menu li").click( function(){...}` I have 3 different `if else` statements. I know there has to be a way to do this by looping through my `currencyData` array and use `this` to target a specific element, but I cannot figure it out.

I want to make this more modular so it can scale up. If I had 30 different currencies, this would not work. I would have to change too many lines of code, where I should just be able to add another currency to the array.

It is live, you can view it [here](http://still-reaches-4133.herokuapp.com/send).

**JS**

```
var currencyData = [
  {
    "currency": "USD",
    "symbol" : "$"
  },
  {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "symbol" : "€"
  },
  {
    "currency": "JPY",
    "symbol" : "¥"
  }
];

/*
 * Inserts <li> list of values into the currency dropdown
*/
$.each( currencyData, function( key, val ) {

  var $li = $("<li name='currency'><a href='#'>" +
    val.currency + "</a></li>");

  $(".dropdown-menu").append( $li );
 });

/*
 * Generate currency symbol and type and swap them depending on which is clicked
*/
$(".dropdown-menu li").click( function() {

 if ( this.textContent === currencyData[0].currency ) {
    getCurrency(currencyData[0].currency, currencyData[0].symbol);

 } else if ( this.textContent === currencyData[1].currency ) {
    getCurrency(currencyData[1].currency, currencyData[1].symbol);

 } else if ( this.textContent === currencyData[2].currency ) {
    getCurrency(currencyData[2].currency, currencyData[2].symbol);
 };
});

/*
 * Swap currency type and symbol
*/
function getCurrency(currency, symbol) {
  // inserts visible currency symbol to form
  var $span = $("<span class='js-currency-symbol' > " + symbol + "</span>");

  // hidden input to save currency symbol
  var $input = $("<input type='text' class='js-hidden-currency-symbol' value=" +
   symbol + " style='display:none' name='currencySymbol'>");

  $('.js-currency-symbol').remove();
  $('.js-currency-btn').text( currency );
  $('.js-input-amount-prepend').append( $span );

  $('.js-hidden-currency-symbol').remove();
  $('.js-currency-btn-group').append( $input );
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group"> <!-- Currency Input Section-->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="js-input-amount-prepend input-amount-prepend">Amount:</span>
      <!-- INSERT  <span class="js-currency-symbol"> -->
      <input type="text" required class="js-payment-amount-input payment-amount-input" name="amount" placeholder="enter amount">
      <div class="btn-group js-currency-btn-group currency-btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn js-currency-btn currency-btn">Currency</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- INSERT li Items -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- INSERT Hidden currency symbol input -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End Currency Input Section-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work with indices instead of elseif statements**

You should write a function that identifies the index of `this.textContent` in the `currencyData` array. Why not try something like this:

```
function myIndexOf(o) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < currencyData.length; i++) {
        if (currencyData[i].currency == o) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Taken from [this Stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604062/javascript-array-indexof-doesnt-search-objects)

Then you can run:

```
currentIndex = myIndexOf(this.textContent)
getCurrency(currencyData[currentIndex].currency, currencyData[currentIndex].symbol);
```

And it's entirely extensible.

**Avoid unnecessary HTML updates**

Seems like you can reduce `$span` to only update the innerHTML of a `span` element rather than reinitializing your `span` element each time you append it to `$('.js-input-amount-prepend')`. This would slightly shorten `getCurrency`

Comment: Thanks. It took me a bit to digest what was happening but I got it and it works great. 
I understand what you're saying about the html. I will work on that now.